# How to create an Ajax request using CSS and HTML without the use of Javascript

Tags: css, html

I have read an article that combining HTML and CSS results in a touring complete language. At my work place we are trying to avoid the use of Javascript for efficiency and client demands.

Where would I start in creating a network request using CSS and HTML only?

This should work when browser has javascript disabled

Comment: Not a duplicate since CSS is touring complete now

Comment: How Turing completeness is even relevant?

Comment: Let's be clear, you **cannot** use AJAX without JavaScript, that's it... the answer below does not address this question in any real way, and in fact it's just a copy-paste from this article: http://zroger.com/blog/ajax-without-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

**ABOUT Ajax:**

1. [Ajax (also AJAX) is short for asynchronous JavaScript and XML.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) **No JavaScript, no Ajax.**
2. JQuery, one lib of JavaScript, can easily achieve the goal of Ajax, [but when JavaScript is disabled, its' Ajax can't work any more.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823143/jquery-if-javascript-is-disabled-enabled)

**ABOUT CSS:**

1. CSS is Cascading Style Sheets, pure CSS actually control the style of your webpage, like font size and font color, not about networking request.

So, maybe you key problem is **how to make a request using HTML**, the answer is using HTML tags like , for [example](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Forms</h2>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page called "/action_page.php".</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Sample code from [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit).

In this example, there is only HTML/CSS in the frontend. Note the **action** attribute in the form tag, it's the server side path of your request to submit. Once you click the button "submit", data in input box will be sent to the specified path in server side, in this example is "/action_page.php", and the click action makes the web page achieve a request without JavaScript.

Ajax， in a sense, is also one type of contact with server (in the way of [Fetch or XMLHttpRequest](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch)) like **pure HTML forms**, the difference between Ajax and pure HTML form is that:

> In Ajax way, make a small request, like update your web account logo, needn't
>   to refresh and download all the web page, but in pure HTML forms you
>   must. And this is the point of **asynchronous** in the **asynchronous 
>   JavaScript and XML**, i.e. **Ajax**.